# Nvidia cuda with Bitmap

Tags: bitmap, cuda

I need help with CUDA C. I am try programming image processing tools. And i can't understand, how use Bitmap(c++) and CUDA. Help me please. P.S. sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide enough detail. Are you refering to the Gdiplus::Bitmap class in Windows or some other bitmap? What are you trying to do with the bitmap?

For image processing applications you would acces the bitmap's memory, copy this to the CUDA device, process the data there and copy the result back to the main memory of the CPU.

I'd recommend CUDA By Example as a good start if you're not familiar with CUDA.